# Storyboard element locations are off

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I am currently building a project using storyboards and am having an issue when trying to select elements. When I try and click on an element, it selects the element a bit under it, and to select a certain element I have to aim above it. I have disabled the adjustment of scroll view insets, so I am not sure as to why this is happening. I've attached some demonstration photos. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Here I am selecting the "Like" Button:

[image]

And here I am selecting the image of a palm tree:

[image]

Comment: this doesn't solve your problem, but have you tried to select your component on your Document Outline ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this does not allow me to drag/drop elements into the NavigationControllerItem, however.

Comment: Might be an Xcode bug?

Comment: Your UINavigationItem should be in the document outline. If it's not, you can drag one into the scene from the Object Library

Comment: Sure, but that does not solve the issue.

Comment: This issue is especially apparent when I try to add a UIView in the navbar, which has to be dragged & dropped. It simply cannot happen in this case.